# "would create a cyclic reference" when creating CodePipeline with deploy action in other stack

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to have my deployment resources in a different stack then my application resources. I have a stack with an auto scaling group that I reference in a second stack to my deployment group. The aws cdk can synth / deploy both stacks until I add the deploy stage to the pipeline (the stage where I assigned the asg) then I get a "cyclic reference" error.

I created a git repo with an cdk example app (https://github.com/codyfy/aws-cdk-pipeline-cyclic-reference-error) that throws the error.

Here is the code snippet where I create the deployment resources and add them to the pipeline (the error only happens after the last line is added):

```
deploy_application = codedeploy.ServerApplication(self, "CodeDeployApplication", application_name="application")
     deployment_group = codedeploy.ServerDeploymentGroup(self, "DeploymentGroup",
            application=deploy_application,
            auto_scaling_groups=[ props ]
        )
        print(deployment_group)
        deploy_action = codepipeline_actions.CodeDeployServerDeployAction(
            action_name="DeployToASG",
            input=source_output,
            deployment_group=deployment_group
        )
        pipeline.add_stage(stage_name="Deploy", actions=[ deploy_action ]) # the deployment group can be created but not assigend to the pipeline
```

where `props` is the asg given as a parameter during construct creation:

```
def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, props: autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
```

This is the error message `cdk synth` is throwing:

```
Error: 'pipeline-stack' depends on 'asg-stack' (dependency added using stack.addDependency(), pipeline-stack -> asg-stack/AutoScalingGroup/InstanceRole/Resource.Arn, pipeline-stack -> asg-stack/AutoScalingGroup/ASG.Ref). Adding this dependency (asg-stack -> pipeline-stack/CodePipeline/ArtifactsBucket/Resource.Arn) would create a cyclic reference.
      at Stack._addAssemblyDependency (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/stack.js:443:19)
      at Object.addDependency (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/deps.js:39:24)
      at Stack.addDependency (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/stack.js:183:16)
      at Stack.prepareCrossReference (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/stack.js:670:28)
      at Stack.prepare (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/stack.js:541:43)
      at Function.prepare (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct.js:87:27)
      at Function.synth (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct.js:51:14)
      at App.synth (/tmp/jsii-kernel-vBZ69a/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/app.js:71:52)
      at /home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7588:51
      at Kernel._wrapSandboxCode (/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:8224:19)
      at /home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7588:25
      at Kernel._ensureSync (/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:8197:20)
      at Kernel.invoke (/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7587:26)
      at KernelHost.processRequest (/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7296:28)
      at KernelHost.run (/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7236:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_embedded/jsii/jsii-runtime.js:7239:37)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.synth()
  File "/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aws_cdk/core/__init__.py", line 3463, in synth
    return jsii.invoke(self, "synth", [])
  File "/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 113, in wrapped
    return _recursize_dereference(kernel, fn(kernel, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 288, in invoke
    args=_make_reference_for_native(self, args),
  File "/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 348, in invoke
    return self._process.send(request, InvokeResponse)
  File "/home/hornung/dev/tests/cdk-pipeline-mwe/.env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 318, in send
    raise JSIIError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
jsii.errors.JSIIError: 'pipeline-stack' depends on 'asg-stack' (dependency added using stack.addDependency(), pipeline-stack -> asg-stack/AutoScalingGroup/InstanceRole/Resource.Arn, pipeline-stack -> asg-stack/AutoScalingGroup/ASG.Ref). Adding this dependency (asg-stack -> pipeline-stack/CodePipeline/ArtifactsBucket/Resource.Arn) would create a cyclic reference.
```

Has someone encountered a similar issue with resources in two different stacks?

Thanks for any help and advice. Have a nice day ;-)